# firing off a javascript function within an option tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got the following dropdown code and for eack of the different selections I'd like to trigger one of my functions

```
<select name="webmenu" id="webmenu">
<option value="UK" id="UK_button" title="assets/images/uk_flag.png">this is the uk</option>
<option value="US" id="US_button" title="assets/images/us_flag.png">this is the us</option>
<option value="EU" id="EU_button" title="assets/images/euro_flag.png">this is the eu</option>
</select>
```

I have this in jquery

```
$('#webmenu').change(function(){

var temp=$(this).children(":selected").val();
switch(temp)
{
    case 'UK':
        alert('Hello UK');
        break;
    case "EU":
        alert("Hi EU");
        break;
    case "US":
        alert("Hi America!");
        break;
}

});
```

but I'd like to only use javascript. Could you help show how to rewrite the jquery code to get the desired effect please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pure js

HTML:

```
<select name="webmenu" id="webmenu" onchange="myFunction()">
<option value="UK" id="UK_button" title="assets/images/uk_flag.png">this is the uk</option>
<option value="US" id="US_button" title="assets/images/us_flag.png">this is the us</option>
<option value="EU" id="EU_button" title="assets/images/euro_flag.png">this is the eu</option>
</select>
```

Javascript:

```
function myFunction() {
    var temp = document.getElementById("webmenu").value;
    switch(temp)
    {
    case 'UK':
        alert('Hello UK');
        break;
    case "EU":
        alert("Hi EU");
        break;
    case "US":
        alert("Hi America!");
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this : create javascript function and call it on change event of select box.

```
<select name="webmenu" id="webmenu" onchange="webmenuChanged(this)">
<option value="UK" id="UK_button" title="assets/images/uk_flag.png">this is the uk</option>
<option value="US" id="US_button" title="assets/images/us_flag.png">this is the us</option>
<option value="EU" id="EU_button" title="assets/images/euro_flag.png">this is the eu</option>
</select>


<script>
function webmenuChanged(selectbox)
{
  var temp=selectbox.value;
  switch(temp)
   {
    case 'UK':
        alert('Hello UK');
        break;
    case "EU":
        alert("Hi EU");
        break;
    case "US":
        alert("Hi America!");
        break;
  }
}
</script>
```

**[JSFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/r2eqeL2a/8/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [onchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/onchange) event.

Eg:

```
var el = document.querySelector('#webmenu');
el.addEventListener('onchange', function(){
   switch (elem.options[e.selectedIndex].value;) {
        case 'UK':
            alert('Hello UK');
            break;
        case "EU":
            alert("Hi EU");
            break;
        case "US":
            alert("Hi America!");
            break;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you do not have multiple on the select, just do

```
var cc = {"UK":"United Kingdom","EU":"Europe","US":"America"}
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("webmenu").onchange=function(){
    var val = this.value;
    alert("Hello "+cc[val]);
  }
}
```

I however strongly suggest you add an option

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/gqw2e2n3/)

```
<option value="">Please select</option>
```

and test the value

```
var cc = {"UK":"United Kingdom","EU":"Europe","US":"America"}
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("webmenu").onchange=function(){
    var val = this.value;
    if (val) alert("Hello "+cc[val]);
  }
}
```

Comment: OP want to make it in javascript only

Comment: Updated - I missed that part

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can do this

```
var elem = document.querySelector('#webmenu');
elem.onchange = function() {
    var temp = elem.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    switch (temp) {
        case 'UK':
            alert('Hello UK');
            break;
        case "EU":
            alert("Hi EU");
            break;
        case "US":
            alert("Hi America!");
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: @mplungjan OP wanted it didn't he?

Answer (score 0):

[**Js Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/synx6ss6/)

you can use `onchange` for select

```
function val() {

    var temp = document.getElementById('webmenu').value

    switch (temp) {
        case 'UK':
            alert('Hello UK');
            break;
        case "EU":
            alert("Hi EU");
            break;
        case "US":
            alert("Hi America!");
            break;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This.  Its working. I have checked it.

```
<html>
    <head>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                function get_value(obj){

                    var e = document.getElementById(obj.id);
                    var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value
                    switch(strUser)
                    {
                        case 'UK':
                            alert('Hello UK');
                            break;
                        case "EU":
                            alert("Hi EU");
                            break;
                        case "US":
                            alert("Hi America!");
                            break;
                    }
                }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select name="webmenu" id="webmenu" onchange="get_value(this);">
            <option value="UK" id="UK_button" title="assets/images/uk_flag.png">this is the uk</option>
            <option value="US" id="US_button" title="assets/images/us_flag.png">this is the us</option>
            <option value="EU" id="EU_button" title="assets/images/euro_flag.png">this is the eu</option>
        </select>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Very poor programming to get the object via its ID after passing the object. Just use var strUser = `obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].value`

Comment: var strUser = obj.value.     This will also give the answer

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

```
document.getElementById('webmenu').addEventListener('change', function() {
    switch(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value) {
        case 'UK':
            alert('Hello UK');
            break;
        case "EU":
            alert("Hi EU");
            break;
        case "US":
            alert("Hi America!");
            break;
    }
}, false);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Make sure the browser supports that. onchange is supported by all

Comment: You'd have to put "attachEvent('onclick', function);" to support IE8. But I'm responding a basic javascript question, not a basic cross browser support one.